# can't get the data from push notification

Tags: android, json, parse-platform, push-notification

i'm trying to add a specific information to a push with this code:

```
JSONObject data;
String message = "Hey pal" + ", it looks like " + cur_user.get("realName") + " added you to the list '" + list_name + "'. press on me to check it.";
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();

try {
    data = new JSONObject();   
    data.put("alert", message);
    data.put("test", "test");

    push.setQuery(query);                    
    push.setData(data);
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} finally {
   push.sendInBackground();
}
```

and in my custom receiver i do this:

```
json = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data");

String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");

try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    Log.d("getNotification", json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but all i get is:

```
D/getNotification﹕ {"NOTIFICATION_TYPE":1,"alert":"Hey pal, it looks like Listo App added you to the list 'fgh'. press on me to check it.","push_hash":"dfa928b7702a61d0863e1ba6df7c9595"}
```

i was looking all over the internet for a solution but couldn't find one.

any ideas?

Comment: you want to get the "test" field which your not getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are not getting "test" field than what you can do is make json object of "message" field adding test into it as field like below:-

```
JSONObject data;

String message = "\"message\":{\"alert\":\"Hey pal" + ", it looks like " + cur_user.get("realName") + " added you to the list '" + list_name + "'. press on me to check it.\",\"test\":\"test\"}";
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();

try {
data = new JSONObject();   
data.put("alert", message);

 push.setQuery(query);                    
 push.setData(data);
} catch (JSONException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
} finally {
   push.sendInBackground();
}
```

the above string make a json object of message which have alert and test field

Comment: and where do i put this line?

Comment: instead of String message line put this line. and don't add test field to data which you are doing `data.put("test", "test");` put only message field

Comment: String message ="\"message\":{\"alert\":\"Hey pal" + ", it looks like " + cur_user.get("realName") + " added you to the list '" + list_name + "'. press on me to check it.\",\"test\":\"test\"}";                                                             data.put("alert", message);                                                                              f           if you mean like that then it doesn't work...

Comment: yes you have to change your String message line to my String message line